# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) I/flutter ( 3257)

Tags: flutter, dart

Console output:

> Performing hot restart...
>
> Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
>
> Restarted application in 3,459ms.
>
> D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 3257): The input method toggled cursor
> monitoring on
>
> D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 3257): The input method toggled cursor
> monitoring on
>
> I/flutter ( 3257): Catched an error!
>
> I/flutter ( 3257): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character
> 1)
>
> I/flutter ( 3257): <br />
>
> I/flutter ( 3257): ^
>
> I/flutter ( 3257): Some issue

My Code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp( const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Trying Xammp First Time',
      home: const Xampp(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.highContrastDark()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Xampp extends StatefulWidget {
  const Xampp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Xampp> createState() => _XamppState();
}

class _XamppState extends State<Xampp> {
  TextEditingController namecontroller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
  Future<void> _login() async {
    var success = false;
    var data =<String, String> {
      "name": namecontroller.text,
      'password': passwordcontroller.text,
    };
    if (namecontroller.text != '' || passwordcontroller.text != '') {
      try {
        final baseurl = "http://10.0.2.2/";
        final url = "$baseurl/practice_api/insert_record.php";
        var res = await http.post(
            Uri.parse(url),
            body: data);
        final response = jsonDecode(res.body);
        success = response["result"] == "Success";
      } catch (e) {
        print("Catched an error!");
        print(e);
        success = false;
      }
    }
    if (success == "true") {
      print('Record Inserted');
      namecontroller.text = "";
      passwordcontroller.text = "";
    }
    else {
      print('Some issue');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Form(
        child:Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: namecontroller,
              decoration:const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter What people call you i-e name ',
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_sharp),
                labelText: 'Name',

              ) ,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: passwordcontroller,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Password',
                icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
            ),
             ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
            _login();
            },
                 child: const Text('Insert')
            ),
          ],
        ) ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: most probably your api ``$baseurl/practice_api/insert_record.php`` is returning HTML and not a valid JSON response !!

Comment: You unconditionally call `jsonDecode(response.body)` without first checking `response.statusCode` to see if your request succeeded.  You likely instead are receiving some HTML error page.

Comment: As the other comments say, this is HTML. `<br />` is usually the beginning of a message that PHP generates during the execution of your script. It is not necessarily an error, it could be a PHP warning or notice. Simply stop your code before `final response = jsonDecode(res.body);` is executed and check the body. You will get detailed info about what's wrong.